# PHP + Curl, get remote file and serve with same headers

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I need a php script that accepts a URL via a get request and I want it to send a request for the URL sending the same headers the visitor used, then return the file using the same headers the server sent.

eg. requested is http://Google.com/
The PHP script uses Curl to request http://Google.com/ sending the same headers as the user's browser sent to the script (eg. browser name)
The data is then sent to the user's browser with the same headers Google sent to the script (eg. cache, ttl etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'd need to set the curlopt `CURLOPT_HEADER` setting as well as the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` setting.  But this will return a single string with the headers on top of the body.  You can then split them with something like:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
list ($headerString, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
$headers = explode("\r\n", $headerString);
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    header($header);
}
echo $body;
```

Now, beware that not all headers should be forwarded (Such as the `Server:` header)...  I'll leave it to you to build a sanity checking function to strip out the non-forwarded headers...